# How to install adobe after effects with wine on ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: graphics, wine, video-editor

I'm a video editor and a film maker. I want to use Adobe After effects to make graphical contents for my work. I would like to install it in my Ubuntu even while I have Windows.

Can I install it on wine or not? I know there is a software Jahshaka, But I want to try to install After Effects with wine. If I can install this, how can I do this?

Comment: You can try it urself and see if it works or not.

Comment: @Faizan I've tried it but couldn't install. But I'm sure that some wine version should be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use after effects 6.5 I installed it and it is working fine plus some good -yet old- plugins like cycore effects and some trapcode

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Could you please elaborate on the why and how? As is stands, your answer is likely to be deleted automatically by the system for being unclear...